# Why is the column-wise multiplication less efficient than the holistic multiplication for computing Schur complement?

Tags: c++, eigen3

We are trying to compute the Schur complement for a large symmetric positive definite matrix H composed of diagonal blocks U and V and offset diagonal blocks W and W' (tranpose of W), and V is a diagonal positive definite matrix. The Schur complement formula is

```
H <-- U - W*V^(-1)*W'                       (1)
```

In implementing the operation, one way is directly using the above equation.

A second way takes advantage of the fact that V has all zeros as its off diagonal elements. Equation 1 is written out and implemented as below

```
H <-- U - \Sigma W_i * V_{ii}^(-1) * (W_i)'      (2)
```

where W_i is the ith column of W, V_{ii} is the ith diagonal element of V, and \Sigma sums over every column of W. Apparently, (2) is expected to be more efficient than (1) as it avoids multiplying whole large matrices.

Both approaches are implemented with the Eigen library in the C++ language and tested on a PC and a mobile device with an intel atom processor.

Surprisingly, on the intel core i7 4-core PC, the code snippet (compiled with gcc, -O3, release mode) for (2) is less efficient than that for (1). The median computation time for (1) and (2) are 0.092 ms, 0.212 ms, respectively, note the ratio 2.30. On the intel atom 4-core processor, the similar (code snippet compiled with clang -O3) is observed. The median computation time for (1) and (2) are 0.575 ms, 1.923 ms, respectively, note the ratio 3.34.

Could anyone help me explain why (2) is slower than (1)?

For your information, the code snippet for both approaches are given below.

```
        // preconditioner
        Eigen::VectorXd p = (H_.diagonal().array() > 1.0e-9).select(H_.diagonal().cwiseSqrt(),1.0e-3);
        Eigen::VectorXd p_inv = p.cwiseInverse();

        // scale H and b
        H_ = p_inv.asDiagonal() * H_ * p_inv.asDiagonal();
        b0_ = p_inv.asDiagonal() * b0_;

        Eigen::MatrixXd U = H_.topLeftCorner(H_.rows() - marginalizationParametersLandmarks,
                                             H_.rows() - marginalizationParametersLandmarks);
        Eigen::MatrixXd V = H_.bottomRightCorner(marginalizationParametersLandmarks,
                                                 marginalizationParametersLandmarks);
        Eigen::MatrixXd W = H_.topRightCorner(H_.rows() - marginalizationParametersLandmarks,
                                              marginalizationParametersLandmarks);
        Eigen::VectorXd b_a = b0_.head(H_.rows() - marginalizationParametersLandmarks);
        Eigen::VectorXd b_b = b0_.tail(marginalizationParametersLandmarks);

        // split preconditioner
        Eigen::VectorXd p_a = p.head(H_.rows() - marginalizationParametersLandmarks);

        // invert the marginalization block
        static const int sdim = SIZE_PARAMETERIZATION_SIZE_FEATURE;
        b0_.resize(b_a.rows());
        b0_ = b_a;
        H_.resize(U.rows(), U.cols());
        H_ = U;

// surprisingly, the below operation is more efficient than its alternative on both
// an intel atom processor and on an intel core i7 PC
#if defined(ANDROID) || defined(__ANDROID__)
        Eigen::VectorXd V_inv(V.cols());
        for (int jack = 0; jack < V.cols(); ++jack) {
            V_inv[jack] = 1.0/V(jack, jack);
        }
        H_ -= W*V_inv.asDiagonal()*W.transpose();
        b0_ -= W*V_inv.asDiagonal()*b_b;
#else
        // assume V off-diagonal elements are all zeros
        Eigen::MatrixXd delta_H(U.rows(), U.cols());
        Eigen::VectorXd delta_b(b_a.rows());
        delta_H.setZero();
        delta_b.setZero();
        for (int i = 0; i < V.cols(); ++i) {
            double V_inv = 1.0 / V(i, i);
            double V_inv_sqrt = std::sqrt(V_inv);
            Eigen::VectorXd M = W.block(0, i, W.rows(), 1) * V_inv_sqrt;
            Eigen::VectorXd M1 = W.block(0, i, W.rows(), 1) * V_inv;
            delta_H += M * M.transpose();
            delta_b += M1 * b_b[i];
        }
        b0_ -= delta_b;
        H_ -= delta_H;
#endif
        // unscale
        H_ = p_a.asDiagonal() * H_ * p_a.asDiagonal();
        b0_ = p_a.asDiagonal() * b0_;
```

Comment: Is it really worth worrying about number-crunching performance on an Atom?

Comment: What timings do you get (how big is the difference)? How far away from theoretical peak-performance are you? Did you compile in release mode and with full architecture support on both systems (`-march=native` for gcc/clang)?

Comment: @chtz As you suggest, I will double check to ensure the  program is compiled in release mode and march=native. The present timing is obtained by taking the difference of the values of std::chrono::system_clock::now() at the start and the end of an operation. I will post the exact timing numbers shortly.

Comment: Short answer: When Eigen sees `V_inv.asDiagonal()` as part of a product, it will of course exploit the fact that this factor has diagonal form. Your manual loop creates lots of temporaries making it inefficient.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me. @chtz